# Runaway argument

Tags: math-mode, errors

Where is my fault here: `\text{Genom att undersöka var kurvan $f_{A}(x)$ skär linjen $T=20$ ser vi att $x\approx {4.3}$ då $f_{A}(x) = 20$`. Error message "Runaway argument".

Comment: there is a missing `}` at the end